# UIScrollView and targetContentOffset doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, cocoa, animation, uiscrollview, scroll

I want UIScrollView to always scroll back to the specific point.
I've achieved it by writing:

```
   - (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset 
{
    (*targetContentOffset).x = 0.0f;
}
```

it works pretty fine with one exception.
When I scroll far enough and reach the end of the view (bouncing starts then) and pull my finger up, the view just scrolls smoothly with deceleration a little back, stops and then jumps (without animation) where I set it.
It doesn't happen as long as I don't scroll to the end of the scroll view.

Here's how I init UIScrollView

```
  scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 284, frame.size.height)];
  scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  scrollView.delegate = self;

  [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(285,frame.size.height)];
  [self addSubview:scrollView];

  UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
  inset.left = 60;
  inset.right = 60;
  [scrollView setContentInset:inset];
```

Answer (score 0):

The bouncing effect is a default behavior when you are reaching the boundaries of the content of scrollview you can turn it off by setting the **bounces** property to **NO**:

```
yourscrollView.bounces = NO;
```

I believe this is only the issue you are facing here.

Comment: Maybe msmialko wants the view to reach the new targetContentOffset with a normal bounce effect

Comment: Disabling the bounces is fixing it in a way, but create another issue: it actually scrolls to the good offset but very, very slowly. No idea on how to fix this yet...